# Insert an additional record for all records in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I insert an additional row for all rows in a table? For example, this is the data in my table -

```
id       num         name           type   occupation    location
1000056  1326120205  CHRISTOPHER    H      Physical      ASHEVILLE, NC
1030026  1326105     Jennifer Ew    F      None N/A      Meridian, MS
```

I want the table to now have -

```
id       num         name           type   occupation    location
1000056  1326120205  CHRISTOPHER    H      Physical      ASHEVILLE, NC
1000056  1326120205  CHRISTOPHER    H      Physical      State - NC
1030026  1326105     Jennifer Ew    F      None N/A      Meridian, MS
1030026  1326105     Jennifer Ew    F      None N/A      State - MS
```

Comment: This is not good relational design.  The state is an attribute of the location, not the person who is represented by a role. I think you will find a lot of usage and maintenance headaches down the road maintaining two rows to represent each person.  I would recommend having a new table called location or city with columns for the city and state.

Comment: This is just junk data to test something. This is not how our prod databases are designed. @Chris94

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t (id, num, name, type, occupation, location)
    select id, num, name, type, occupation, 'State - ' || substr(location, -2)
    from t;
```